# Sort table by Month Name

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do I sort table by Month Name?

I have a dataset which uses direct query that I would like to have sorted by month name, how do I set this up?

Comment: You want to sort them by alphabetical order or by order of the months? It's unclear on how you've asked the question. Can you elaborate and explain what's currently being shown?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to sort a table by Month is to create a date variable which denotes the month. For eg: Jan-2020 could be shown as 1/1/2020. This would make sure your sorting always works. If you are looking to sort, just by month (without year), then you can add a month number field and use that for sorting:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sort-by-month-name-in-power-bi/